# Parse CSV text with accents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does anyone know how to parse text like this:

```
informaci\u00f3n del aplicante
```

so that it ends up like this?

```
información del aplicante
```

This is my method:

```
def translations_to_csv(translations, headers, to_file_performance=false, file_name = nil)
  csv_output = ""
  CSV::Writer.generate(csv_output, fs = "\t") do |csv|
    if to_file_performance
      csv_string = ""
      CSV::Writer.generate(csv_string) do |csv_str|
        csv_str << headers.collect { |item| item.upcase }
      end
      File.open(file_name,'a') {|f| f.write(csv_string) }
    else
      csv << headers.collect { |item| item.upcase }
    end

    translations.each do |data|
      row = headers.collect { |item| data.first[item.to_sym] }
      csv << row
    end
  end
  csv_output
end
```

The CSV exports most text correctly, but some text with accents will look like the first example.

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.5

Comment: Parse it how, to do what?

Comment: I just edit it. Sorry

Comment: It may already be correct, but you are not displaying it in the console correctly, or need to change the encoding for your output format or device. Could you please show a little more code/context. When you see `"informaci\u00f3n del aplicante"`, assuming it is assigned to a variable `str`, could you also show `str.encoding` and `str.bytes.to_a` - these will give better idea of what is really going on with this string.

Comment: Done bro I added some code.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain which variable contains the problem string in your code, and give the results of  calling  `.encoding` and `.bytes.to_a` for it? Also, could you explain how you are viewing `csv_output` when you see the incorrect output? If you are checking in a console, you may just need to set the console to display UTF-8 (which is not really to do with Ruby)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7133889/525478

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7 isn't aware of multi-byte characters. It's nicely handled by Ruby v2.0+. I'd suggest you get off the old, buggy, unsupported version and upgrade to v2.2+ at a minimum, failing to do that will make more work for you. You don't say what OS you're on, but the recommended way is to use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install). In either case read the installation directions.